# How to create a wav file from a textfile?

Tags: wav, carrierwave, text-files, duration

I have a textfile, it stores the frequency and parts' durations of a wav file for example:

44100hz
150 010 150 015 133...

These informations describe the wavfile will be created with 44100hz of frequency, 50ms with volume 100, 10ms with volume 0, 50ms with volume 100, 15ms with volume 0 and 33ms with volume 100... I dont know how to set the duration when I be writing wav file.  Does an element in 'data array' store amplitude of (1/frequency) seconds? Can you help me?

p/s: I'm sorry about my English, I am using C# to code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know myself, but [Garrett Hoofman](http://www.visionsofafar.com/dablog/author/Garrett%20Hoofman.aspx) created [a wrapper for creating WAV files in C#](http://www.visionsofafar.com/dablog/post/2008/10/21/Wave-File-Format-and-C.aspx).

By taking your data you should be able to use [Generating Sound Waves with C# Wave Oscillators](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Generating-Sound-Waves-with-C-Wave-Oscillators) on the MSDN to actually create the data from your file.

Here is the WAV File spec from the Garret's WaveLibrary library.

```
 * Wave File Library
 * A simple library to write a wave file
 * 
 * Garrett Hoofman
 * 10/21/08
 * http://www.visionsofafar.com
 * */

/* Wave File Format
Reference : http://ccrma.stanford.edu/CCRMA/Courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
The canonical WAVE format starts with the RIFF header:
0         4   ChunkID          Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
                               (0x52494646 big-endian form).
4         4   ChunkSize        36 + SubChunk2Size, or more precisely:
                               4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size)
                               This is the size of the rest of the chunk 
                               following this number.  This is the size of the 
                               entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes for the
                               two fields not included in this count:
                               ChunkID and ChunkSize.
8         4   Format           Contains the letters "WAVE"
                               (0x57415645 big-endian form).

The "WAVE" format consists of two subchunks: "fmt " and "data":
The "fmt " subchunk describes the sound data's format:
12        4   Subchunk1ID      Contains the letters "fmt "
                               (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
16        4   Subchunk1Size    16 for PCM.  This is the size of the
                               rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
20        2   AudioFormat      PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
22        2   NumChannels      Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
24        4   SampleRate       8000, 44100, etc.
28        4   ByteRate         == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
32        2   BlockAlign       == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               The number of bytes for one sample including
                               all channels. I wonder what happens when
                               this number isn't an integer?
34        2   BitsPerSample    8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
          2   ExtraParamSize   if PCM, then doesn't exist
          X   ExtraParams      space for extra parameters

The "data" subchunk contains the size of the data and the actual sound:
36        4   Subchunk2ID      Contains the letters "data"
                               (0x64617461 big-endian form).
40        4   Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               This is the number of bytes in the data.
                               You can also think of this as the size
                               of the read of the subchunk following this 
                               number.
44        *   Data             The actual sound data.
*/
```